# RichTextEditor deleting all Links and images from HTML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

I Have used RichText Editor to edit HTML recieving from Server but all links and images in HTML got removed by when use to edit ...

[image: Original HTML as String]

When Opened in RichTextEditor

[image: After Editing]

Comment: If I didn't already use up all my flags for the day, I'd use one on this. I have no idea what this question is about.

Comment: fully iOS flag , anyone can help me are good with Objective C